# Python: argparse reading csv file to function

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, argparse, optparse

I'm using argparse and I want something like: test.py --file hello.csv

```
def parser():
   parser.add_argument("--file", type=FileType('r'))
   options = parser.parse_args()

   return options

def csvParser(filename):
   with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
       csv.reader(f)
       ....
   ....
   return par_file

csvParser(options.filename)
```

I get an error: TypeError coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found.

How would I be able to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `FileType()` `argparse` type returns an *already opened* fileobject.

You don't need to open it again:

```
def csvParser(f):
   with f:
       csv.reader(f)
```

From the [`argparse` documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#type):

> To ease the use of various types of files, the `argparse` module provides the factory `FileType` which takes the `mode=`, `bufsize=`, `encoding=` and `errors=` arguments of the `open()` function. For example, FileType('w') can be used to create a writable file:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> >>> parser.add_argument('bar', type=argparse.FileType('w'))
> >>> parser.parse_args(['out.txt'])
> Namespace(bar=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='out.txt' encoding='UTF-8'>)
> ```

and from the [`FileType()` objects](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) documentation:

> Arguments that have `FileType` objects as their type will open command-line arguments as files with the requested modes, buffer sizes, encodings and error handling (see the `open()` function for more details)

Comment: So, how do you think I would be able to take this already opened fileobject and parse it through a function I created? I see, but I would want it so a user would be able to type the filename into the command prompt

Comment: @TTT: File objects are just objects. Pass it to the function.

Comment: @TTT: Your user **is** able to type in the filename. `argparse` then opens that file for you and gives you the resulting fileobject.

Comment: Ah! Thank you that makes perfect sense. Thank you. I will use this as the answer.